# How to check a calendar event already exists or not

Tags: ios, calendar

How to check the event already exists in calendar or not. I am adding an event to the calendar. The event is added to a particular date which is coming from API correctly, but it is added to many times. I need to add the event for a date only once.

How to over come these problem?

```
case 6: {
    [APP_SHARE startIndicator];
    EKEventStore *store = [EKEventStore new];

    [store requestAccessToEntityType:EKEntityTypeEvent completion:^(BOOL granted, NSError *error)
    {
        if (!granted) { return; }

        EKEvent *event = [EKEvent eventWithEventStore:store];

        event.title = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Event Name=%@ Date & Time=%@",[arr_response valueForKey:@"post_title"],[arr_response valueForKey:@"time"]];

        NSString *myDateString = [arr_response valueForKey:@"time"] ;
        // Convert the string to NSDate

        NSArray* str_latlon_array = [myDateString componentsSeparatedByString: @","];
        NSLog(@"%@",[str_latlon_array objectAtIndex: 0]);

        NSString* str=[str_latlon_array objectAtIndex: 0];

        NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = @"dd/MM/yyyy";

        NSDate *today = [dateFormatter dateFromString:str];
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = @"EEEE";
       // NSString *dayName = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:today];


        event.startDate = [today dateByAddingTimeInterval:60*60]; //today
       // NSLog(@"%@",today);
        event.endDate = [today dateByAddingTimeInterval:60*60];  //set 1 hour meeting
        event.calendar = [store defaultCalendarForNewEvents];
        NSError *err = nil;
       ; [store saveEvent:event span :EKSpanThisEvent commit:YES error:&err];

        savedEventId = event.eventIdentifier;

         [APP_SHARE stopIndicator];
         [AppDelegate defaultAlert:@"Information" message:@"Data Saved in Calender"];
    }];
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically.. don't add it multiple times. The portion of code you posted is called multiple times.

To do this, save the `savedEventId` somewhere in your app. This depends on what that event represents, how many events your app saves and so on.

If your app adds just one event, you can use `NSUserDefaults` to store `savedEventId` on a specific key (e.g. `@"myEventId"`). You'd afterwards be able to check if you already saved the event (by checking with `NSUserDefaults`), and if the event still exists in `EventKit` (in the case that you always want to recreate it, but if the user deleted it, it should stay deleted in my opinion).

Alternatively, if your app adds multiple events to Calendar, you must obviously store the `savedEventId` for all the events the app added, on unique keys. You could do this in a database (e.g. using `CoreData`).